# how can I export the data from my sqlite3 database to some json or csv file

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I do not know much about it, but I'm currently using the sqlite3 plugin in ionic 3, and I'm storing forms that users use. I would like at a certain moment to export this data to some conventional format such as json or csv. is this possible? and how?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite Porter plugin. Don't worry this is an ionic plugin.

## Installation

Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite-porter
```

and then add the plugin to your module.

and on exporting you're data from your database to for example json (exportDbToJson(db))

## usage

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Test", "1.0", "TestDB", 1 * 1024);
        var successFn = function(json, count){
                console.log("Exported JSON: "+json);
                alert("Exported JSON contains equivalent of "+count+" SQL statements");
            };
        cordova.plugins.sqlitePorter.exportDbToJson(db, {
            successFn: successFn
        });
```

## for more information please visit

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite-porter/
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#exportdbtojson
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I do not understand in what folder this json is generated. Is it possible to write a record to record json according to the data that is inserted in my table? I do not want to export the database, only the data.

Comment: console.log("Exported JSON: "+json); , I have log the result . It is in you where you want to load this json but this is already the ouput. Its in you if you store it to database and make and api to get the data or extract it and store it on a textfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command line sqlite binary:

```
sqlite3 -csv /path/to/sqlite/file 'SELECT * FROM yourtable'
```

You can obviously construct whatever query you like.